# How to limit Google Form submissions based on total number of answers not number of responses

Tags: google-apps-script, limit, google-forms

I created a simple registration form that only asks for:

1. Email address (required)
2. Name (required)
3. Name of plus one person (not required - if there is one)

I can limit a Google Form based on the number of responses:

```
function closeForm() {
    // get active form
    var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();

    // retrieve number of responses thusfar
    var responses = form.getResponses();

    // set close message
    var msg = "We're sorry, the event is full.";

    // do the math
    if(responses.length >= 100) {
        form.setAcceptingResponses(false).setCustomClosedFormMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

but I cannot figure out how to set the limit as the sum of 1 and 2. (namely the total number of seats in a theatre)

Could someone help me out?

Comment: I think you can query the reponses/response sheet and then calculate how many seats have been filled so,  you can then use that as condition.

Comment: Indeed, I can query the sheet and get the total number of names entered, but I'm sure not how to get that number back to the form's script editor.

Comment: Oh ok. I have posted the answer with sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the restless help of [@Chris W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1691677/chris-w) and [@Umair](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/5647272/umair) I was finally able to create a form that does what I initially wanted.

The following script is placed in the form's script editor and triggered on form submit:

```
function FormDisabling() {

    var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
    var msg = 'Sorry, the event is full.';
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Total');
    var range = sheet.getRange('d21’);
    var data = range.getValue();

    if (data <= 40) {
      form.setAcceptingResponses(false).setCustomClosedFormMessage(msg);
   }

}
```

It only works if the form and spreadsheet attached are set up like this:
A second sheet (Total) is populated from the original (Responses) sheet with an extra (D) column added. D2-D20 have a countif formula (`=COUNTIF(A2:B2;"<>")`), while cell D21 totals these values. If its value is greater than the number set in the script, the form disables and the custom message is shown.

I'm sure there is a less hacky way to the original question. I'm sorry for the dumb questions and comments, it was my first foray into Apps Script (and logical thinking in a while).

Answer (score 1):

Use an [onFormSubmit Event](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) **on the form** to run a script every time the form is submitted. You can then loop on the plusOne column, checking for null values, to get the total number of attendees.

```
function onEdit(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses"); //change to match your sheet.
  var currentGuests = sheet.getRange("GuestCountCell with A1Notation").getValue(); //get current count from cell on spreadsheet defined above.

  //Do other stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. I can get the total number of names by querying the sheet to another one and then adding a column with a COUNTIF formula and a SUM in the cell at the 101st row. The problem is that I don't know how to get this value back to my original script upon submit.

Comment: @elbatron Oh, you didn't mention that before. Updated my answer. I have to run. Be back in a few hours.

Comment: Thanks again. It seems that SpreadsheetApp is not defined if I use the above snippet in the form script editor.

Comment: How could the form see the value currentGuests, if I use the snippet in the sheet's editor?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. You need to run this on [form submit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

```
function calculateTodayReservedSeats() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID);
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var person1 = sheet.getRange(2, PERSON1_COLUMN_INDEX, lastRow - 1, 1).getValues();
    var person2 = sheet.getRange(2, PERSON2_COLUMN_INDEX, lastRow - 1, 1).getValues();
    var i, count;
    for (i = 0; i < person1.length; i++) {
        count += person1[i][0];
        count += person2[i][0];
    }

    if (count > LIMIT) {
        //Do your stuff
        //You can disable your form
    }
}
```

You need to define following constants :

- SPREADSHEET_ID
- SHEET_NAME
- PERSON1_COLUMN_INDEX
- PERSON2_COLUMN_INDEX
- LIMIT

This is untested code, let me know if this doesn't works, we can debug. If it's work then you can accept solution/upvote.

Comment: Thanks Umair. I have know idea how to run this code on a form submit trigger. Help says that it's an installable trigger. Does that mean that I have to run this code outside sheets/forms editor? It's my first dealing with Google apps.

Comment: I think, no. You can simply configure to trigger your function on form submit. I think it's at Spreadsheet-based trigger > On Form Submit - Event

Comment: I'm getting: Cannot convert NAME to (class) error while running the script. NAME is PERSON1_COLUMN_INDEX's name.

Comment: Thanks. Now to code runs without error, however the form accepts responses even the count is greater than the limit. [script on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/9wk7QCWJ)

Comment: where have you initialized the `form` ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/b5rHzr01 with `form`. The trigger is set to From form and On form submit, but it still allows more submissions than the limit set in the script.

Comment: Try this https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app#openbyidid and try running your function manually and see if any error is thrown. Try decreasing the `limit` and see if it disables the form.

Comment: Changed the var to OpenByID and lowered the limit to 3. The script ran without errors, but the form stills accepts submissions more than 3. (even more responses than 3).

Comment: Created a new form, copy-pasted the script, changed the IDs and the sheet name, but no luck.

Comment: First of all try this https://pastebin.com/wrc8A9SL then check log and form is disabled or not. You're testing form as user [in incognito mode] right ? Maybe form is not disabled for editors ?

Comment: Thanks for not letting it go. Pasted test code, hooked up trigger to the new function, checked the ID and debug says: form and msg undefined and the console log empty... I'll set up a new form and check everything again in a few hours. Is there a way to share the form with you?

Comment: How is form and msg undefined ? We're initializing it with FormApp.openById() and string, right ?

Comment: I have no idea... here is a screenshot: https://pasteboard.co/H8WsOO6.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165704/discussion-between-elbatron-and-umair).